# Ubuntu server 14.04 possibly going to sleep?

Tags: debian, suspend

I have a web server(apache) running on Ubuntu 14.04. It has been running fine for years. It is a VM on a vmware host. About a month ago we restored it to a new vmware host from a backup because the original host crashed.

Yesterday I noticed it was not serving requests. It's not a server I monitor so it's possible it's been acting up since the restore. I ssh'd in fine but when running commands like "top" it just hangs. I can ctrl-c to get back to the prompt but that's about it.

Being that ssh wasn't working we opened the console via vmware and found that we could run commands as normal. So we did a "sudo reboot". Once rebooted ssh was working fine again. Apache started serving requests as well.

From there I setup a monitor to make a web request every five minutes to the server. A short time later, 10-15mins, I received an alert that the web site was not responding. Again the same scenario occurred - cannot do anything from ssh, but using the console we can reboot. Unfortunately I have not found a pattern with the duration between reboot and re-occurence yet.

ssh is exhibiting some odd behavior, however the console acts normal. So I'll keep the focus on the topic that it seems the server is either going to sleep or bogging down after a certain period of time.

With that being said while this issue is occurring we have run "top" from the console and see minimal cpu activity, less than 1% usage. Same goes for memory. I am waiting for the issue to happen again so I can see what iotop shows. But for now it doesn't seem anything is bogging it down.

So my next guess is it's going to sleep. If that is the case can someone point me to where I'd look on Ubuntu server to find if it's configured to go to sleep? Or does anyone have any other suggestions on what might be happening?

EDIT:

It seems other issues coincide on other servers on this VM host. So it's looking more like this is a host or network issue. We don't have the resources to keep trying to figure this out so we are going to build new machines.

Comment: Without logs, ps outputs, and a minimum of investigation on your side, it will be quite difficult to help you. If need be, reboot it with an image of a live system to collect logs, and start monitoring the CPU with SNMP for instance, to understand what is happening. A read only disk message also usually means disk hardware problems.

Comment: Exactly what Rui Ribeiro said.  Forget about apache for a moment and try to sort out ssh, i.e. one thing at a time.  You will need to provide a lot more information about the server for anyone to be able to help you.  e.g. Did you install the OS?  Did you configure it, and what did you change? If not, is the person who installed/configured the OS available?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I've been investigating for hours. What logs would like to see? I have run "top" from the console while experiencing the issues from another computer while ssh'd in. "top" is showing no spikes in cpu or memory.

Comment: I have written some generic guidelines, but please do keep in mind it is not in the spirit of this forum. You are more than welcome to keep coming here with specific questions. Cheers.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro if the spirit of this forum is to go about helping with the tone you have then I'm better off going elsewhere.

Comment: Please read our FAQ about questions and do not take take it personally;  I hope my answer  gets you somewhere.

Comment: I have redone my entire question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I re-did my question but it is now closed. We figured out the issue. How do I go about opening it back up so I can provide the answer? Or should I just make a comment?

Comment: We can reopen it easily while it is on hold. What was it?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the short version is the old VM host that had crashed was not powered down and somehow started working again. So sporadically traffic was going to the old server which was when we saw the issues.

Comment: We all been there with old machines/VM going up, sometimes after a power failure...IMO it is not worth it to invoke a moderator to try to open this question for that kind of answer. It is good you found it. The first point of off-topic questions is exactly "Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) "

Answer (score 0):

For possible debbuging strategies, this is my advice:

Test the disk extensively booting from a live Linux media. Having a read only disk, it is a bad symptom of media corruption. With (very) bad luck you have hard disk sector errors, however the fact that you are telling us the vmware image came from a crashed machine might mean that simply the underlying VM image/vmdk is corrupted, or worse there are corrupted binaries.

I would migrate/reinstall to other machine *without* using vmware import/export mechanisms, and *without* copying the vmdk *if* I could not find underlying physical disk defects (in the vmware host).

As for the file logs, they stop being meaningful as soon the kernel activates the read-only mount to protect data integrity. Redirect syslog errors to other `syslog` server and to another virtual console (some distributions redirect logs to a virtual console *by default*). With luck, you will able to see an error log giving a clue of the cause.

Still about logs, you have not mentioned *vmware logs*. If there are underlying physical disk defects, they will appear in the vmware logs - after all the VM is only seeing a virtual disk image given by the vmware hypervisor. Go to the vmware terminal console, and watch them. If possible, redirect the vmware logs also to another syslog server to watch them regularly.

As for continuous maintenance, it is good practice to install SNMP agents, and using cacti, observium or whatever fancies you, for having baselines of the regular usage of the resources. That can also come handy in case of problems, and can also send you automated alerts.